# The setting could not be created error message

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, xen, citrix

Whenever I open Word or attempt to change the Autorecover files location I see an error that just says `The setting could not be created`. The only option is to press OK.

The location is set to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\microsoft\Word` and my account has full r/w access to that folder. Other users on the domain have the same setting.

Any idea how I stop the error appearing?

Office 2010 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Citrix Xenapp)

Comment: Have you tried repairing Word yet?  Is there more than one version of Word/Office installed on the machine in question?  Is this you personal setup, or was it supplied by your company?

Comment: This is on a Citrix server. Only one instance of Office 2010. I'm using a brand new user profile. It's technically supplied by my company but I have full control over it. The error is server agnostic, doesn't matter which one I connect to which suggests the error lies in my user profile somewhere. I can't work out what it is though - as I said - it's a brand new profile.

Comment: Ok, then this is definitely off-topic for SU, as SU is for home hardware.  You should flag a mod and request this be migrated to ServerFault (I voted to close it for migration to SF).   One piece of advice based on what's here: you may want to confirm if any GPOs are set to control Word (and its autosave location).

Comment: Ok. flagged to move to SF. I'll check the policies but I'm receiving the same ones as most other users who do not get the error.

Comment: I'm not *really* convinced its off topic here - now, if Mr JF was the server admin, this would be a different story, but as an end user, he's in our domain.

Comment: I am both a domain user and a domain admin..